# How to do partial fill in D3?

Tags: css, d3.js

I have a curve running above or below a sloped line and I want to fill the area just above the line and below the curve, but not the area below the line and above the curve, as illustrated in the left image.

Again, it is easy to fill like right image, but I want to fill like in left image. So, how to get rid of the unwanted fill?

```
svg.append("path").attr("class", "line").attr("d", peak(pp)).style({ fill: peakColor, opacity: 0.5 });
```

[image]

Comment: You would need to draw a second path to fill for this.

Comment: @Lars I guess you misread my question. I want to get rid the filling of red circled part, not fill that part. Anything above the straight line (and below the curve) should be filled. There might be many zig-zags.

Comment: Yes, so instead of filling the original path, you append a second one that covers only the area you want filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is something I came up with for me in case anybody cares about it.

```
var slope = (dp.rightY - dp.leftY) / (dp.rightX - dp.leftX);  // slope of the line
var pp = [];
pp.push({ x: dp.leftX, y: dp.leftY });
var wasAbove = true;   // track if it's above the line
data.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.x >= dp.leftX && d.x <= dp.rightX) {
        var yAtLine = (d.x - dp.leftX) * slope + dp.leftY;
        if (d.y > yAtLine) {
            if (!wasAbove)
                pp.push({ x: d.x, y: yAtLine });
            pp.push(d);
            wasAbove = true;
        } else if (wasAbove) {
            pp.push({ x: d.x, y: yAtLine });
            wasAbove = false;
        }
    }
});
pp.push({ x: dp.rightX, y: dp.rightY });
var peak = d3.svg.line().x(function (d) { return xScale(d.x) }).y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y) });
svg.append("path").attr("class", "line").attr("d", peak(pp)).style({ fill: peakColor, opacity: 0.5 });
```